# Find all positive solutions such that $n^2 + 9n +1$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

**My Attempt**

$n^2 + 9n +1$ is obviously not a perfect square when it is in between consecutive squares, or: $n^2 + 8n +16 < n^2 + 9n +1 <n^2 + 10n +25$

The second inequality is always true. Solving the first inequality, we get it  is not true when $n \le 15$. So we check for possible values less than 16. On working mod 3, we get that $n$ must be a multiple of $3$. So possible candidates are $3,6,9,12$ and $ 15$. On working out, $n=15$ is the only solution.

I inquire if there are any other shorter methods, or methods which are usually done, like taking the discriminant of the expression or by modular arithmetic. I tried the first method and proved that there is integral $n$ when $ \sqrt {77+4c}$ is integral ( Where $c= n^2 + 9n +1$) It works mod 4, and I couldn't continue. I am not sure modular arithmetic would work, as 15 is the only solution, but I would like to know of any other, even if it is reasonably longer than my method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What set is n in ? You seem to imply that 15 is the only solution but another (obvious) one would be 0 since $0^2 + 9 *0 +1 = 1^2$

Comment: @Astyx 0 is not a positive solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We know that:

$$ (n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n +1 < n^2 + 9n +1 < n^2 + 10n + 25 = (n+5)^2 $$

So there are only 3 cases:

$$ n^2 + 9n + 1 = (n+i)^2 , i \in \{2, 3, 4\}  $$

Solving each case separately, we get respectively for i = 2, 3, 4:

$$ 5n =  3 $$
$$ 3n =  8 $$
$$ 1n = 15 $$

Answer (score 7):

The usual way to solve these questions is as you've done: bound the expression between two consecutive perfect squares, and prove that the bounds are strict for large $ n $.

The reason that one shouldn't expect a solution using modular arithmetic is that it is too "short-sighted": the question of whether a number is a perfect square or not depends on the *exact* multiplicity of the primes dividing it, whereas modular arithmetic only provides upper and lower bounds. This suggests that our solution must depend on a global approach.

Here is an alternative solution. We may write (completing the square):

$$ \left( n + \frac{9}{2} \right)^2 - x^2 = \frac{77}{4} $$

$$ (2n + 9)^2 - (2x)^2 = 77 $$

$$ (2n - 2x + 9)(2n + 2x + 9) = 77 $$

Now,  we simply check all factors of $ 77 $ to see if they provide solutions. The given hypotheses mean that we must only check two cases: $ 2n + 2x + 9 = 11, 77 $, and the latter gives a solution.

Comment: I like this answer more than mine!

Comment: I made a very similar answer without knowing that someone made the same and was faster.

Comment: Independent answers are fine by me.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions only for $n=0$ and $n=15$.

Clearly, $n=0$ produces a perfect square. Say now that $n>0$ and 
$$n^2+9n+1=k^2,$$ 
for some $k\ge 1$. Then $(k+1)(k-1)=n(n+9)>n(n+2)$.
Thus $k-1>n$. Let $k-1=n+v$, where $v$ a positive integer. Then
$$
(n+v+2)(n+v)=n(n+9),
$$
and hence
$$
n(7-2v)=v^2+2v.
$$
Hence, if such $v$ exists, it can only be $v\in\{1,2,3\}$. The cases $v=1,2$ lead to contradiction. Indeed, for $v=1$, we have $5n=3$, and for $n=2$, we have $3n=8$.

Meanwhile, for $v=3$, we have
$$
n=15,
$$
for which $n^2+9n+1=361=19^2$.

Answer (score 2):

We want to solve $$m^2=n^2+9n+1$$ over the integers.

Multiplying with $4$ gives

$$4m^2=4n^2+36n+4=(2n+9)^2-77$$

So, we have $$(2m-2n-9)\cdot (2m+2n+9)=-77$$

For every integer pair $(a,b)$ with $ab=-77$ solve the equation system

$$2m-2n-9=a$$

$$2m+2n+9=b$$

(adding the two equations shows that the solution is always unique) and verify whether $m$ and $n$ are integers and $n$ is positive.

Comment: @starfall Didn't notice that. Shall I delete my answer ?

Comment: I don't mind - it's up to you.

Comment: Only delete an answer if embarrasses you.